# capture string in one indexed position and move to another indexed position in xml file

Tags: python, regex, xml, latex

I am a Python beginner and want to convert an existing xml file to a LaTeX document. The xml contains a lot of  footnotes that sometimes are split - as they did not fit on one page in the original document (an old book) and the creator of the xml file wanted to have a layout as close to the original document as possible. Between the split footnotes there is normal text as well as other footnotes ...
The following code should make the relation between the footnotes clear:

```
> normal text <note place="foot" n="(a)" xml:id="seg2pn_8_1"
> next="#seg2pn_8_2">aaa aaa aaa</note> normal text <note place="foot"
> n="(b)">footnote text</note>. normal text. <note place="foot" n="(a)"
> xml:id="seg2pn_8_2" prev="#seg2pn_8_1">bbb bbb bbb</note>
```

the desired output would be:

```
normal text \footnote{aaa aaa aaa bbb bbb bbb} normal text \footnote{footnote text}. normal text.
```

Everything can be between the two parts of the note: normal text, other notes etc.
Using regex’ lookbehind and lookahead and pythons zip method I was able to print the desired result: but I am unable to do the actual replacement and write the result ot a second file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile,'r') as f:
   fin = f.read()

   strings_first = (re.findall('(?<=seg2pn_\d{1}_2">).*?(?=</note>)', fin, flags=re.DOTALL)) 
   strings_second = (re.findall('(?<=seg2pn_\d{1}_1">).*?(?=</note>)', fin, flags=re.DOTALL))

   for t, y in zip(strings_first, strings_second):
     print(t + y)
```

Comment: Can you post what the desired output would be, so that it is clear which text is moving to what position?

Comment: I edited it and hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: Doing this using regular expression processing, without a proper XML parser, is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in an XSLT solution, it's pretty simple. Just do an identity transformation with the added rules:

```
<xsl:template match="note[@place='foot'][@next]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="id(substring(@next, 2))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note[@place='foot'][@prev]"/>
```

This separates the footnote-cleanup into a separate phase of processing, which is always a good idea to keep the logic of this kind of application simple.

I'm assuming a footnote is never split into more than two parts.

Comment: Thank you: If I chose the wrong tool for this task I am definitely grateful for this info. I will try to figure out how to use this solution on my xml file. However: I am surprised that this is  so difficult with regular expressions.

Comment: Well, for a start, XML attributes can appear in any order, and that makes them very hard to match with regexes. Also there's a lot of flexibility for whitespace (`<note/>` might be written `<note  />`) and if you want to do it properly you have to skip anything that's within a comment...

Comment: But now I need to figure out how to actually transforming the file using your style sheet. Any hints on where to start?

Comment: May be best to start with a new question, in which you can explain what you tried and how it failed. It's hard to explain where to start in a 600-character comment when we don't know what your difficulties are.