# Transform xml with xsl merging split footnotes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

folfowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734736/capture-string-in-one-indexed-position-and-move-to-another-indexed-position-in-x?noredirect=1#comment125055901_70734736) advice and the given solution I want to merge split footnotes of this huge xml dokument.  This is a part of the document. Below you find what I want to achieve in a summarized form.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fussnoten.xsl"?
<?xml-model href="http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/basisformat.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">     <teiHeader>
<fileDesc>
<titleStmt>
<title type="main">System des heutigen Römischen Rechts</title>
<title type="volume" n="2">Zweyter Band</title>
<author>
<persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/118605909">
<surname>Savigny</surname>
<forename>Friedrich Carl von</forename>
</persName>
</author>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/115266127">
<surname>Geyken</surname>
<forename>Alexander</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/1222198746">
<surname>Haaf</surname>
<forename>Susanne</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/1019062681">
<surname>Jurish</surname>
<forename>Bryan</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName>
<surname>Boenig</surname>
<forename>Matthias</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName>
<surname>Thomas</surname>
<forename>Christian</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<editor corresp="#DTACorpusPublisher">
<persName>
<surname>Wiegand</surname>
<forename>Frank</forename>
</persName>
</editor>
<respStmt>
<orgName ref="https://www.bbaw.de">Berlin-Brandenburgische Akademie der Wissenschaften (BBAW)</orgName>
<resp>
<note type="remarkResponsibility">Langfristige Bereitstellung der DTA-Ausgabe</note>
<ref target="https://www.bbaw.de"/>
</resp>
</respStmt>
</titleStmt>
<editionStmt><edition>Vollständige digitalisierte Ausgabe.</edition></editionStmt>
<extent>
<measure type="images">577</measure>
<measure type="tokens">125822</measure>
<measure type="types">13706</measure>
<measure type="characters">890572</measure>
</extent>
<publicationStmt>
<publisher xml:id="DTACorpusPublisher">
<email>dta@bbaw.de</email>
<orgName role="project">Deutsches Textarchiv</orgName>
<orgName role="hostingInstitution" xml:lang="eng">Berlin-Brandenburg Academy of Sciences and Humanities (BBAW)</orgName>
<orgName role="hostingInstitution" xml:lang="deu">Berlin-Brandenburgische Akademie der Wissenschaften (BBAW)</orgName>
<address>
<addrLine>Jägerstr. 22/23, 10117 Berlin</addrLine>
<country>Germany</country>
</address>
</publisher>
<pubPlace>Berlin</pubPlace>
<date type="publication">2021-02-18T14:40:37Z</date>
<availability>
<licence target="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.de">
<p>Distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 License.</p>
</licence>
</availability>
<idno>
<idno type="URLWeb">https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/savigny_system02_1840</idno>
<idno type="URLXML">https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/download_xml/savigny_system02_1840</idno>
<idno type="URLHTML">https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/download_html/savigny_system02_1840</idno>
<idno type="URLText">https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/download_text/savigny_system02_1840</idno>
<idno type="DTADirName">savigny_system02_1840</idno>
<idno type="DTAID">16928</idno>
<idno type="URN">urn:nbn:de:kobv:b4-200905195268</idno>
</idno>
</publicationStmt>
<sourceDesc>
<bibl type="MM">Savigny, Friedrich Carl von: System des heutigen Römischen Rechts. Bd. 2. Berlin, 1840.</bibl>
<biblFull>
<titleStmt>
<title level="m" type="main">System des heutigen Römischen Rechts</title>
<title level="m" type="volume" n="2">Zweyter Band</title>
<author>
<persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/118605909">
<surname>Savigny</surname>
<forename>Friedrich Carl von</forename>
</persName>
</author>
</titleStmt>
<editionStmt>
<edition n="1"/>
</editionStmt>
<extent>
<measure type="pages">VI, 559 S.</measure>
</extent>
<publicationStmt>
<publisher><name>Veit</name></publisher>
<pubPlace>Berlin</pubPlace>
<date type="publication">1840</date>
</publicationStmt>
</biblFull>
<msDesc>
<msIdentifier>
<repository>Staatsbibliothek zu Berlin &#x2013; Preußischer Kulturbesitz</repository>
<idno>
<idno type="shelfmark">SBB-PK, Gb 13171-2&lt;b&gt;</idno>
<idno type="URLCatalogue">http://stabikat.de/DB=1/SET=12/TTL=1/CMD?ACT=SRCHA&amp;IKT=1016&amp;SRT=YOP&amp;TRM=694059153</idno>
</idno>
</msIdentifier>
<physDesc>
<typeDesc>
<p>Fraktur</p>
</typeDesc>
</physDesc>
</msDesc>
</sourceDesc>
</fileDesc>
<encodingDesc>
<editorialDecl>
<p>Dieses Werk wurde gemäß den <ref target="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/richtlinien">DTA-Transkriptionsrichtlinien</ref>
im Double-Keying-Verfahren von Nicht-Muttersprachlern erfasst und in XML/TEI P5 nach
<ref target="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/basisformat">DTA-Basisformat</ref> kodiert.</p>
<p/>
</editorialDecl>
<tagsDecl>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="aq">font-family:sans-serif</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="b">font-weight:bold</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="blue">color:blue</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="c">display:block; text-align:center</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="et">display:block; margin-left:2em; text-indent:0</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="et2">display:block; margin-left:4em; text-indent:0</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="et3">display:block; margin-left:6em; text-indent:0</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="f">border:1px dotted silver</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="fr">border:1px dotted silver</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="g">letter-spacing:0.125em</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="i">font-style:italic</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="in">font-size:150%</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="k">font-variant:small-caps</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="larger">font-size:larger</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="red">color:red</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="right">display:block; text-align:right</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="s">text-decoration:line-through</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="smaller">font-size:smaller</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="sub">vertical-align:sub; font-size:.7em</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="sup">vertical-align:super; font-size:.7em</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="u">text-decoration:underline</rendition>
<rendition scheme="css" xml:id="uu">border-bottom:double 3px #000</rendition>
</tagsDecl>
</encodingDesc>
<profileDesc>
<langUsage>
<language ident="deu">(Früh-)Neuhochdeutsch</language>
<language ident="deu">German</language>
</langUsage>
<textClass>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#dtamain">Fachtext</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#dtasub">Recht</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#dwds1main">Wissenschaft</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#dwds1sub">Jura</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#DTACorpus">core</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#DTACorpus">ready</classCode>
<classCode scheme="https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/klassifikation#DTACorpus">china</classCode>
</textClass>
</profileDesc>
</teiHeader>
<text>     <front>
<pb facs="#f0001"/>
<pb facs="#f0002"/>
<pb facs="#f0003"/>
<pb facs="#f0004"/>
<pb facs="#f0005"/>
<pb facs="#f0006"/>
<pb n="[I]" facs="#f0007"/>
<titlePage type="main">         <docTitle>           <titlePart type="main">             <hi rendition="#g"><hi rendition="#b">Sy&#x017F;tem</hi><lb/>
des</hi>             <lb/>
<hi rendition="#b">heutigen Römi&#x017F;chen Rechts</hi>           </titlePart>         </docTitle>         <lb/>
<byline>von<lb/>
<docAuthor><hi rendition="#g">Friedrich Carl von Savigny</hi>.</docAuthor></byline>         <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>         <titlePart type="volume">           <hi rendition="#b"><hi rendition="#g">Zweyter Band</hi>.</hi>         </titlePart>         <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>         <titlePart type="desc">Mit K. Bairi&#x017F;chen und K. Würtembergi&#x017F;chen Privilegien.</titlePart>         <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>         <docImprint>           <pubPlace>             <hi rendition="#g">               <hi rendition="#b">Berlin.</hi>             </hi>           </pubPlace>           <lb/>
<publisher>             <hi rendition="#g">Bei Veit und Comp.</hi>           </publisher>           <lb/>
<docDate>             <hi rendition="#g">               <hi rendition="#b">1840.</hi>             </hi>           </docDate>         </docImprint>       </titlePage>     </front>     <body>       <lb/>
<pb n="[II]" facs="#f0008"/>
<pb n="[III]" facs="#f0009"/>
<div type="contents">         <head>           <hi rendition="#c">             <hi rendition="#b">Inhalt des zweyten Bandes.</hi>           </hi>         </head>         <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>         <p><hi rendition="#b">Zweytes Buch.</hi> <hi rendition="#g">Die Rechtsverhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e</hi>.<lb/>
<hi rendition="#g">Zweytes Kapitel</hi>. Die Per&#x017F;onen als Träger der Rechts-<lb/>
verhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e.</p>         <lb/>
<list>           <item>             <hi rendition="#right">Seite.</hi>           </item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 60. Natürliche Rechtsfähigkeit und deren po&#x017F;itive Mo-<lb/>
dificationen <ref>1</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 61. Gränzen der natürlichen Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">I.</hi> Anfang <ref>4</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 62. Gränzen der natürlichen Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">I.</hi> An-<lb/>
fang. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>12</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 63. Gränzen der natürlichen Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Ende <ref>17</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 64. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit. Einleitung <ref>23</ref></item>           <lb/>
<pb n="IV" facs="#f0010"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Inhalt des zweyten Bandes.</fw>           <lb/>
<item>             <hi rendition="#right">Seite.</hi>           </item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 65. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">I.</hi> Unfreyheit <ref>30</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 66. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Mangel der<lb/>
Civität <ref>38</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 67. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit. <hi rendition="#aq">III.</hi> Abhängig-<lb/>
keit von Familiengewalt <ref>49</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 68. Dreyfache <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> <ref>60</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 69. Wirkungen der <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> <ref>69</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 70. Wirkungen der <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio.</hi> (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>79</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 71. Anomali&#x017F;che Rechte in Beziehung auf Rechtsfähig-<lb/>
keit und <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> <ref>90</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 72. Anomali&#x017F;che Rechte in Beziehung auf Rechtsfähig-<lb/>
keit und <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio.</hi> (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>104</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 73. Anomali&#x017F;che Rechte in Beziehung auf Rechtsfähig-<lb/>
keit und <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio.</hi> (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>121</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 74. Anomali&#x017F;che Rechte in Beziehung auf Rechtsfähig-<lb/>
keit und <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio.</hi> (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>134</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 75. Heutige Anwendbarkeit der Lehre von der Rechts-<lb/>
fähigkeit und der <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> <ref>148</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 76. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit durch Infamie.<lb/>
Einleitung <ref>170</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 77. Einzelne Fälle der Infamie <ref>173</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 78. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Bedeutung der Infamie <ref>186</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 79. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Bedeutung der Infamie. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>195</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 80. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Bedeutung der Infamie. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>201</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 81. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Bedeutung der Infamie. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>209</ref></item>           <lb/>
<pb n="V" facs="#f0011"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Inhalt des zweyten Bandes.</fw>           <lb/>
<item>             <hi rendition="#right">Seite.</hi>           </item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 82. Nebenwirkungen der Infamie <ref>215</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 83. Heutige Anwendbarkeit der Lehre von der Infamie <ref>224</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 84. Ein&#x017F;chränkung der Rechtsfähigkeit durch Religion <ref>231</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 85. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Begriff <ref>235</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 86. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Arten <ref>242</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 87. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Ge&#x017F;chichte <ref>246</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 88. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Ge&#x017F;chichte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung) <ref>253</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 89. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Ent&#x017F;tehung und Untergang <ref>275</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 90. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte <ref>281</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 91. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>285</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 92. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>294</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 93. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>299</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 94. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>310</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 95. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Rechte. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>317</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 96. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Verfa&#x017F;&#x017F;ung <ref>324</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 97. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Verfa&#x017F;&#x017F;ung. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>329</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 98. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Verfa&#x017F;&#x017F;ung. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>339</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 99. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Verfa&#x017F;&#x017F;ung. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>345</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 100. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Verfa&#x017F;&#x017F;ung. (Fort&#x017F;etzung.) <ref>352</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 101. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Fiscus <ref>360</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 102. Juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;onen. Erb&#x017F;chaften <ref>363</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item>§. 103. Ver&#x017F;chiedenheiten in der Verknüpfung der Rechts-<lb/>
verhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e mit den Per&#x017F;onen <ref>374</ref></item>           <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>
<pb n="VI" facs="#f0012"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Inhalt des zweyten Bandes.</fw>           <lb/>
<item>             <hi rendition="#right">Seite.</hi>           </item>           <lb/>
<item><hi rendition="#g">Beylage</hi> <hi rendition="#aq">III.</hi> Die Vitalität eines Kindes, als Bedingung<lb/>
&#x017F;einer Rechtsfähigkeit <ref>385</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item><hi rendition="#g">Beylage</hi> <hi rendition="#aq">IV.</hi> Über die Wirk&#x017F;amkeit der von Römi&#x017F;chen Skla-<lb/>
ven contrahirten Obligationen <ref>418</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item><hi rendition="#g">Beylage</hi> <hi rendition="#aq">V.</hi> Über die Schuldenfähigkeit einer <hi rendition="#aq">filiafamilias</hi> <ref>430</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item><hi rendition="#g">Beylage</hi> <hi rendition="#aq">VI. Status</hi> und <hi rendition="#aq">Capitis deminutio</hi> <ref>443</ref></item>           <lb/>
<item><hi rendition="#g">Beylage</hi> <hi rendition="#aq">VII.</hi> Über einige zweifelhafte Punkte in der Lehre<lb/>
von der Infamie <ref>516</ref></item>         </list>       </div>       <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>
<pb facs="#f0013"/>
<pb facs="#f0014"/>
<pb n="[1]" facs="#f0015"/>
<div n="1">         <head/>         <div n="2">           <head><hi rendition="#b">Zweytes Kapitel.</hi><lb/>
Die Per&#x017F;onen als Träger der Rechtsverhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e.</head>           <lb/>
<div n="3">             <head>§. 60.<lb/>
<hi rendition="#g">Natürliche Rechtsfähigkeit und deren po&#x017F;itive<lb/>
Modificationen</hi>.</head>             <lb/>
<p><hi rendition="#in">J</hi>edes Rechtsverhältniß be&#x017F;teht in der Beziehung einer<lb/>
Per&#x017F;on zu einer andern Per&#x017F;on. Der er&#x017F;te Be&#x017F;tandtheil<lb/>
de&#x017F;&#x017F;elben, der einer genaueren Betrachtung bedarf, i&#x017F;t die<lb/>
Natur der Per&#x017F;onen, deren gegen&#x017F;eitige Beziehung jenes<lb/>
Verhältniß zu bilden fähig i&#x017F;t. Hier i&#x017F;t al&#x017F;o die Frage<lb/>
zu beantworten: Wer kann Träger oder Subject eines<lb/>
Rechtsverhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;es &#x017F;eyn? Die&#x017F;e Frage betrifft das mo&#x0364;g-<lb/>
liche <hi rendition="#g">Haben</hi> der Rechte, oder die <hi rendition="#g">Rechtsfähigkeit</hi>,<lb/>
nicht das mögliche <hi rendition="#g">Erwerben</hi> der&#x017F;elben, oder die <hi rendition="#g">Hand-<lb/>
lungsfähigkeit</hi>, welche er&#x017F;t in einem folgenden Ab-<lb/>
&#x017F;chnitt betrachtet werden wird (§ 106).</p>             <lb/>
<p>In dem Rechtsverhältniß aber &#x017F;teht eine be&#x017F;timmte<lb/>
Per&#x017F;on in Beziehung bald zu einer gleichfalls be&#x017F;timmten<lb/>
einzelnen Per&#x017F;on, bald unbe&#x017F;timmt zu allen anderen Men-<lb/>
&#x017F;chen (§ 58). Die gegenwärtige Unter&#x017F;uchung kann ihrer<lb/>
<fw type="sig" place="bottom"><hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> 1</fw><lb/>
<pb n="2" facs="#f0016"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Buch <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Rechtsverhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e. Kap. <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Per&#x017F;onen.</fw><lb/>
Aufgabe nach nur die be&#x017F;timmten Per&#x017F;onen in den Rechts-<lb/>
verhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;en betreffen, da zu dem blos negativen Verhält-<lb/>
niß, in welchem Alle einem Einzelnen, z. B. einem Ei-<lb/>
genthümer, gegenüber &#x017F;tehen, ein Jeder als fähig anzu-<lb/>
&#x017F;ehen i&#x017F;t.</p>             <lb/>
<p>Alles Recht i&#x017F;t vorhanden um der &#x017F;ittlichen, jedem ein-<lb/>
zelnen Men&#x017F;chen inwohnenden Freyheit willen (§ 4. 9.<lb/>
52) <note place="foot" n="(a)"><hi rendition="#aq"><hi rendition="#i">L.</hi> 2 <hi rendition="#i">de statu hom.</hi> (1.5.):<lb/>
&#x201E;Cum igitur <hi rendition="#i">hominum causa<lb/>
omne jus constitutum</hi> sit; pri-<lb/>
mo de personarum statu .. di-<lb/>
cemus.&#x201D;</hi></note>. Darum muß der ur&#x017F;prüngliche Begriff der Per-<lb/>
&#x017F;on oder des Rechts&#x017F;ubjects zu&#x017F;ammen fallen mit dem Be-<lb/>
griff des Men&#x017F;chen, und die&#x017F;e ur&#x017F;prüngliche Identität bei-<lb/>
der Begriffe läßt &#x017F;ich in folgender Formel ausdrücken:<lb/>
Jeder einzelne Men&#x017F;ch, und nur der einzelne Men&#x017F;ch, i&#x017F;t<lb/>
rechtsfähig.</p>             <lb/>
<p>Inde&#x017F;&#x017F;en kann die&#x017F;er ur&#x017F;prüngliche Begriff der Per&#x017F;on<lb/>
durch das po&#x017F;itive Recht zweyerley, in der aufge&#x017F;tellten<lb/>
Formel bereits angedeutete, Modificationen empfangen,<lb/>
ein&#x017F;chränkende und ausdehnende. Es kann nämlich er&#x017F;tens<lb/>
manchen einzelnen Men&#x017F;chen die Rechtsfähigkeit ganz oder<lb/>
theilwei&#x017F;e ver&#x017F;agt werden. Es kann zweytens die Rechts-<lb/>
fähigkeit auf irgend Etwas außer dem einzelnen Men&#x017F;chen<lb/>
übertragen, al&#x017F;o eine juri&#x017F;ti&#x017F;che Per&#x017F;on kün&#x017F;tlich gebil-<lb/>
det werden.</p>             <lb/>
<p>Der gegenwärtige Ab&#x017F;chnitt &#x017F;oll nun zuer&#x017F;t die Grän-<lb/>
zen der in ihrem ur&#x017F;prünglichen oder natürlichen Begriff<lb/>
<pb n="3" facs="#f0017"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">§. 60. Natürliche Rechtsfähigkeit.</fw><lb/>
aufgefaßten Per&#x017F;on fe&#x017F;t&#x017F;tellen, dann aber die zwiefachen<lb/>
Modificationen angeben, wodurch in un&#x017F;rem po&#x017F;itiven<lb/>
Recht die&#x017F;er natürliche Begriff umgebildet worden i&#x017F;t.</p>             <lb/>
<p>Zum Schluß i&#x017F;t noch die ver&#x017F;chiedene Wei&#x017F;e zu er-<lb/>
wähnen, in welcher das einzelne Rechtsverhältniß mit be-<lb/>
&#x017F;timmten Per&#x017F;onen verknüpft werden kann.</p>           </div>           <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>           <fw type="sig" place="bottom">1*</fw>           <lb/>
<pb n="4" facs="#f0018"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Buch <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Rechtsverhältni&#x017F;&#x017F;e. Kap. <hi rendition="#aq">II.</hi> Per&#x017F;onen.</fw>           <lb/>
<div n="3">             <head>§. 61.<lb/>
<hi rendition="#g">Gränzen der natürlichen Rechtsfähigkeit</hi>. <hi rendition="#aq">I.</hi> Anfang.</head>             <lb/>
<p>Der Anfang der natürlichen Rechtsfähigkeit i&#x017F;t bedingt<lb/>
renlos wurde, und er&#x017F;t die <hi rendition="#aq">Lex Julia caducaria</hi> den Heim-<lb/>
fall an den Staat allgemein einführte <note place="foot" n="(c)" xml:id="seg2pn_84_1" next="#seg2pn_84_2"><hi rendition="#aq"><hi rendition="#k">Cicero</hi> de legibus II. 19.</hi></note>. &#x2014; Nehmen<lb/>
<pb n="505" facs="#f0519"/>
<fw type="header" place="top"><hi rendition="#aq">Status</hi> und <hi rendition="#aq">Capitis deminutio.</hi></fw><lb/>
wir nun nach die&#x017F;er Stelle an, daß die Ve&#x017F;talin aus der<lb/>
Agnation austrat, und erwägen wir zugleich, daß &#x017F;ie nach<lb/>
dem ausdrücklichen Zeugniß keine <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> erlitt,<lb/>
&#x017F;o liegt darin eine unmittelbare Widerlegung der Mey-<lb/>
nung des Paulus, welche jeden Austritt aus der Agna-<lb/>
tion für eine <hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> erklärt. Zugleich dient aber<lb/>
die&#x017F;e Stelle zu einem voll&#x017F;tändigen Beweis der von mir<lb/>
behaupteten Unvoll&#x017F;tändigkeit der alten Definition der <hi rendition="#aq">c. d.</hi><lb/>
als einer <hi rendition="#aq">Status mutatio.</hi> Denn eine Veränderung des<lb/>
<hi rendition="#aq">Status</hi> lag für die Ve&#x017F;talin allerdings in der verlornen<lb/>
Agnation, ja auch &#x017F;chon (wenn man etwa den Verlu&#x017F;t der<lb/>
Agnation nicht zugeben wollte) in der Befreyung von der<lb/>
väterlichen Gewalt; erlitt &#x017F;ie nun dennoch keine <hi rendition="#aq">capitis<lb/>
deminutio,</hi> &#x017F;o muß wohl unter die&#x017F;er etwas Anderes zu<lb/>
ver&#x017F;tehen &#x017F;eyn, als die bloße Veränderung des <hi rendition="#aq">Status.</hi><lb/>
So i&#x017F;t al&#x017F;o durch die&#x017F;es vollgültige alte Zeugniß meine<lb/>
Meynung gegen den Vorwurf ge&#x017F;ichert, die Definition der<lb/>
alten Juri&#x017F;ten willkührlich mei&#x017F;tern zu wollen.</p>             <lb/>
<p>Eine ähnliche, nur weniger voll&#x017F;tändige Unter&#x017F;tützung<lb/>
gewährt un&#x017F;rer Meynung Dasjenige, was über die Weihe<lb/>
des <hi rendition="#aq">flamen Dialis</hi> berichtet wird. Auch die&#x017F;er trat aus<lb/>
der väterlichen Gewalt <note place="foot" n="(d)"><hi rendition="#aq"><hi rendition="#k">Tacitus</hi> ann. IV 16. <hi rendition="#k">Ga-<lb/>
jus</hi> I. § 130. <hi rendition="#k">Ulpian.</hi> X. § 5.</hi></note>, und auch bey ihm war die&#x017F;e<lb/>
wichtige Veränderung &#x017F;eines <hi rendition="#aq">Status</hi> ent&#x017F;chieden nicht als<lb/>
<hi rendition="#aq">capitis deminutio</hi> anzu&#x017F;ehen <note place="foot" n="(e)"><hi rendition="#aq"><hi rendition="#k">Gajus</hi> III. § 114.</hi></note>. Die Parallele wäre voll-<lb/>
<note place="foot" n="(c)" xml:id="seg2pn_84_2" prev="#seg2pn_84_1"><hi rendition="#aq"><hi rendition="#k">Ulpian.</hi> XXVIII. 7.</hi> Vgl. Zeit-<lb/>
&#x017F;chrift für ge&#x017F;chichtl. Rechtswi&#x017F;&#x017F;en-<lb/>
&#x017F;chaft B. 2 S. 378.</note><lb/>
<pb n="506" facs="#f0520"/>
<fw type="header" place="top">Beylage <hi rendition="#aq">VI.</hi></fw><lb/>
kommen, wenn es &#x017F;ich bewei&#x017F;en ließe, daß der <hi rendition="#aq">flamen</hi> auch<lb/>
aus der Agnation 
(bey den Neueren <hi rendition="#aq">ereptitium</hi>) verwandelt.</p>           </div>         </div>       </div>       <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="#hr"/>     </body>     <back>       <div type="imprint">         <p>           <hi rendition="#et">Gedruckt bei den Gebr. <hi rendition="#g">Unger</hi>.</hi>         </p>       </div>       <lb/>
<pb facs="#f0574"/>
<pb facs="#f0575"/>
<pb facs="#f0576"/>
<pb facs="#f0577"/>
</back>   </text> </TEI>
```

As I have no experience with xslt I consulted this tutorial and  this xslt should work but it doesn't what is wrong? How do I actually get the desired output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="note[@place='foot'][@next]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="id(substring(@next, 2))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="note[@place='foot'][@prev]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
> normal text <note place="foot" n="(a)" xml:id="seg2pn_8_1"
> next="#seg2pn_8_2">aaa aaa aaa</note> normal text <note place="foot"
> n="(b)">footnote text</note>. normal text. <note place="foot" n="(a)"
> xml:id="seg2pn_8_2" prev="#seg2pn_8_1">bbb bbb bbb</note>
```

the desired output would be:

```
normal text \footnote{aaa aaa aaa bbb bbb bbb} normal text \footnote{footnote text}. normal text.
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your `note` elements are in a namespace, so the match patterns won't match them (search for "XSLT default namespace" to find hundreds of other users who have fallen down this hole).

Also, some XSLT 1.0 processors pre-date the introduction of `xml:id`, so there's no guarantee that such processors will treat `xml:id` as an ID attribute, unless you have a DTD that defines it as such. It's safer to define a key and use the `key()` function:

```
<xsl:key name="xml-id-key" match="*[@xml:id]" use="@xml:id"/>
```

then replace `id(x)` by `key('xml-id-key', x)`

Comment: Can I not just remove the namespace in the original xml document?  I think it is not possible for me at the moment to achieve the result as I lack the necessary knowledge.

Comment: You just need to bind a namespace in the stylesheet, for example `xmlns:t="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"` then write `match="t:note"`. But if you're going to be writing XSLT, then I'd recommend reading some books or tutorials rather than trying to learn by trial and error: it will save time in the long run.